# Japanese text is making error

Tags: android

[image: error]

See picture. Making an app with a Japanese app name and showing error. It's not creating Main Activity file and just getting error everywhere.

Any help would be awesome. Only beginner.

Comment: Why the downvote for this question? Really guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not support Non-English package names. Move your app to a different package that uses only English characters.

Remember, you can always change the displayed name of the app:

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

See "@string/app_name"? That points to a string in your `res/values/strings.xml`. So, you can make that Japanese if you'd like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">デジタ</string>
</resources>
```